# How do you add or strip a new line based on a condition in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the the following list:

```
b = ['B-PER 0 3 Joe', 'B-LOC 13 20 Angola', 'B-ORG 28 35 ABC', 'I-ORG 37 52 Financial', 'I-ORG 54 59 Center', 'B-LOC 72 80 Angola']
```

I want to write each item in the list to a string and create a new line if the item in the list does not start with "I-". If the item does start with "I-" I want to join that line to the previous line.

The closest I can get is the below:

```
a = ''
b = ['B-PER 0 3 Joe ', 'B-LOC 13 20 Angola ', 'B-ORG 28 35 ABC ', 'I-ORG 37 52 Financial ', 'I-ORG 54 59 Center ', 'B-LOC 72 80 Angola ']
for item in b:
    if not re.match(r'^I-.*', item):
        a += item + '\n'
    else:
        a += item.strip('\n')
        
print(a)
```

OUTPUT Received:

```
B-PER 0 3 Joe 
B-LOC 13 20 Angola 
B-ORG 28 35 ABC 
I-ORG 37 52 Financial I-ORG 54 59 Center B-LOC 72 80 Angola
```

OUTPUT Desired:

```
B-PER 0 3 Joe 
B-LOC 13 20 Angola 
B-ORG 28 35 ABC I-ORG 37 52 Financial I-ORG 54 59 Center 
B-LOC 72 80 Angola
```

I'm guessing it's a combination of my conditional logic and order. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stuff like this, it's sometimes easier to create a nested list, add items as appropriate, and then use `str.join()` afterwards once it's fully-constructed.

```
a = []
b = ['B-PER 0 3 Joe ', 'B-LOC 13 20 Angola ', 'B-ORG 28 35 ABC ', 'I-ORG 37 52 Financial ', 'I-ORG 54 59 Center ', 'B-LOC 72 80 Angola ']
for item in b:
    if not re.match(r'^I-.*', item):
        a.append([])
    a[-1].append(item)

print('\n'.join(''.join(line) for line in a))
# B-PER 0 3 Joe 
# B-LOC 13 20 Angola 
# B-ORG 28 35 ABC I-ORG 37 52 Financial I-ORG 54 59 Center 
# B-LOC 72 80 Angola
```